# Importing jpeg files returns black image in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I created a convolutional network that classifies images. All the images were of a jpeg file format, but I had to create a function that would process the images before feeding it into my network.

This is the import functioned I defined:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def import_image(image_location):
    image_contents = tf.read_file(image_location)
    decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(contents=image_contents, channels=3)
    cropped_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(decoded_image, 100, 100)

    return cropped_image
```

After running the program for 22 iterations, I saw that the classification accuracy was terrible. I, at first, attributed its failure to the number of iterations I had tasked to it. I soon added TensorBoard functionality and with the function `tf.summary.image("Cropped Image", cropped_image)`, I saw that the input image was completely black. I then added histograms and summary scalars displaying the cross entropy vs. iterations and this is what came out:[image: Histogram][image: Cross Entropy]

After seeing that the input image is completely black, the results make sense. The network is not being trained at all. So, what's wrong with the import function? Or have I not used `tf.summary.image()` appropriately? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of `image_location` that you are passing to your function?

Comment: Sure, "C:\Users\Espresso\Desktop\images\01.JPG." It's just the path to the image.

Comment: Did you try running that function without the cropping part. Could it be that you are cropping out a blank region of the image?